# Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit Windows updates stuck on pending

Tags: windows, updates

I have a issue where several updates, 13 at last count, are stuck at pending and haven't successfully installed. This problem started on 18th December and the last pending update was 19th January. There have been updates over this period that have installed successfully while the next one or the one before could be stuck on pending.

I tried to get help on the Microsoft Community but we never got it resolved. To be honest after trying a few suggestions and them not working the support engineer stopped replying to any of my queries on the forum.

[Microsoft Community Forum help page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/update-kb3035583-stuck-on-pending-even-after/7097266b-129e-474d-9ff3-514ecc193e02?auth=1)

The link above goes to the page where I originally posted the request for help and details the steps that were tried in an attempt to resolve the issue.

Can anyone on this forum help me get to the root of this problem and get it resolved as I am concerned that some of the pending updates could be security related and not having them installed is putting my PC at risk.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You indicated you have 12 pending updates.  You don't tell us what they are.  Can't help without key information like that.

Comment: Download and run this Microsoft fixit in aggressive mode, reboot an run windows updates again....http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9665683

Comment: @Ramhound I followed the steps in Moab's reply and now when I view my update History it is blank. All it says is _"You have not tried to install any updates from your computer"_  Because of this I can not tell you what the pending updates were. Moab I ran MicrosoftEasyFix50202.msi in aggressive mode. All it seems to have done is delete any update history so I don't know what the pending updates area :( The pending update problem still exists :(

Answer (score 0):

Install Tweaking.com's Windows Repair (All in One) and run both fix for Windows Update in Safe mode. If that doesn't work, run the File Permissions fix and then run the Windows Update fix again (also in Safe mode). When all the usual fixes failed for me recently, this one worked.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I'm in the process of backing up all my data for a clean reinstall of Windows. Once I have it up and running again the way I want it I'm going to look into something like a recovery disc or ISO image